# Laravel Multiple Foreign Keys on Intermediate Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, eloquent-relationship

I have the following table structure:

- default_tasks

  - id
  - ...
- locations

  - id
  - ...
- users

  - id
  - ...
- default_task_location

  - id
  - location_id
  - default_task_id
  - default_assignee_id (FK to users.id)

In my blade file I'm looping through the default tasks for the location, and trying to output the default assigned user. I can get the ID by doing `$task->pivot->default_assignee_id`, but I want to get the actual user model so I can output the user's name in my blade file

I've gathered from searching that the way to accomplish this is to create a pivot table model. So I've done this:

```php
class DefaultTaskLocationPivot extends Pivot
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'default_assignee_id');
    }

    public function defaultTask()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DefaultTask::class);
    }

    public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
    }
}
```

and in my location model I've done this:

```php
public function taskDefaultAssignee()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
        ->using(DefaultTaskLocationPivot::class)->withPivot(['default_task_id', 'frequency_type_override', 'create_on_day_override', 'due_on_day_override', 'default_assignee_id']);
}
```

However, I'm still unable to access the user associated with the `default_assignee_id`. I've tried things like `$task->location->taskDefaultAssignee`, but it doesn't seem like the relationship is even available if I dump the object.

Comment: ***default_task_location*** is not seems a *pivot* table

Comment: What about if you use `$task->location->pivot->user->name`?